# How can I convert a GUID into a byte array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order to save data traffic we want to send our GUID's as array of bytes instead of as a string (with the use of Google Protocol Buffers).

How can I convert a string representation of a GUID in Ruby to an array of bytes:

Example:

```
Guid: 35918bc9-196d-40ea-9779-889d79b753f0
=> Result: C9 8B 91 35 6D 19 EA 40 97 79 88 9D 79 B7 53 F0
```

In .NET this seems to be natively implemented: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example GUID is in a Microsoft specific format. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding):

> Other systems, notably Microsoft's marshalling of UUIDs in their COM/OLE libraries, use a mixed-endian format, whereby the first three components of the UUID are little-endian, and the last two are big-endian.

So in order to get that result, we have to move the bits around a little. Specifically, we have to change the endianess of the first three components. Let's start by breaking the GUID string apart:

```
guid = '35918bc9-196d-40ea-9779-889d79b753f0'
parts = guid.split('-')
#=> ["35918bc9", "196d", "40ea", "9779", "889d79b753f0"]
```

We can convert these hex-strings to binary via:

```
mixed_endian = parts.pack('H* H* H* H* H*')
#=> "5\x91\x8B\xC9\x19m@\xEA\x97y\x88\x9Dy\xB7S\xF0"
```

Next let's swap the first three parts:

```
big_endian = mixed_endian.unpack('L< S< S< A*').pack('L> S> S> A*')
#=> "\xC9\x8B\x915m\x19\xEA@\x97y\x88\x9Dy\xB7S\xF0"
```

- `L` denotes a 32-bit unsigned integer (1st component)
- `S` denotes a 16-bit unsigned integer (2nd and 3rd component)
- `<` and `>` denote little-endian and big-endian, respectively
- `A*` treats the remaining bytes as an arbitrary binary string (we don't have to convert these)

If you prefer an array of bytes instead of a binary string, you'd just use:

```
big_endian.bytes
#=> [201, 139, 145, 53, 109, 25, 234, 64, 151, 121, 136, 157, 121, 183, 83, 240]
```

---

PS: if your actual GUID isn't Microsoft specific, you can skip the swapping part.

Comment: Hi @Stefan - about your last point: "If your actual GUID isn't Microsoft specific, you can skip the swapping part." - what do you mean by this exactly? How would I tell if a GUID I have is "Microsoft specific"? Is there some kind of tell?