# Ruby: Convert Byte Array to Integer?

Tags: c#, ruby

I am trying to duplicate this snippet of `C#` code in `Ruby`:

```
var guid = Guid.Parse("a823efd8-c8c1-4cf5-9aad-3b95d6f11371");
byte[] a = guid.ToByteArray();
var bigInteger = new BigInteger(a, isUnsigned: true);
```

I've gotten as far as creating the byte array with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788845/how-can-i-convert-a-guid-into-a-byte-array-in-ruby/54790603#54790603):

```rb
guid = 'a823efd8-c8c1-4cf5-9aad-3b95d6f11371'
parts = guid.split('-')
mixed_endian = parts.pack('H* H* H* H* H*')
big_endian = mixed_endian.unpack('L< S< S< A*').pack('L> S> S> A*')
byte_array = big_endian.bytes
#=> [216, 239, 35, 168, 193, 200, 245, 76, 154, 173, 59, 149, 214, 241, 19, 113]
```

I'm not sure what to do to convert this array of bytes into an integer - line 3 of the `C#` example above. Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way would be to just do the calculation. The C# code is actually [treating the bytes as little endian](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Byte___), which is why we reverse the array first here:

```ruby
byte_array.reverse.inject(0) {|m, b| (m << 8) + b }
```

(This gives me 150306322225734326370696054959344185304 with your input.)

I don’t think there is a direct method to convert a binary string or an array of bytes to an integer. I suspect that any more efficient way would need to have the internal representation of the integer exposed.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I pored over that page yesterday and completely missed the fact that it treats the bytes as little endian. And your solution makes sense - take the total, shift it over by 1 byte, then add the current byte we're on. Brilliant. Thanks again!